# Is it possible to cast a type parameter?

Tags: c#, dictionary, casting, boxing

According to the Implicit converting Logic which enables something like:

```
string str = "something";
Object o = str ;
```

I was expecting that assigning a `Dictionary<string, string>` to `Dictionary<string, Object>` would be possible, but this is not the case.

Is it possible to explicity cast the string value to Object without having to iterate through the keyValuePair-items?

EDIT1: replaced all Boxing/Unboxing words with converting and casting as comments and answers mention this isnt [Boxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) issue.

Thank you all

Comment: string -> object does not require boxing. string is a reference type. [Boxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) is used for value types.

Comment: You mean co- and contravariance. Please read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx) to understand why it is not possible for a Dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typecasting doesn't help you there but you can convert one to another with LINQ:

```
Dictionary<string, object> newDict;
newDict = dict.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => (object)pair.Value);
```

Comment: While this does compile and run, strictly speaking it still just internally iterates through the KeyValuePairs which is something the OP says he was trying to avoid - though it's not entirely clear *why* he was trying to avoid that...

Comment: Considering the OP doesnt know LINQ and the otion to directly cast analoge to normal casting doesnt work, its the fastest way to achieve this conversion, allthough it Loops the Dictionary internaly it still seems to be the best avaiable solution. thanx all again

Answer (score 1):

This is not about boxing, it is about covariance and contravariance.

Generic type paremeters are not covariant. So you can't do that, at least in C# 3.0. In C# 4.0 the concept is implemented with the aid of `in` and `out` keywords, but the generic dictionary haven't changed.

You can read more about covariance and contravariance [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx) and its following parts.

Answer (score 1):

If there were a read-only dictionary interfaces `IReadableDictionary<TKey, out TValue>` and `IReadableDictionary<TValue>` (using type 'Object' in the indexer), it would be possible for code which needed to read, but not write, a dictionary to accept any dictionary with values of a type compatible with the desired type (the second interface would be used to allow code which wants to retrieve instances of `basicThing` associated with instances of of `Mammal`, to accept things like `Dictionary<Cat, basicThing>` or `Dictionary<Animal, DerivedThing>`).  It would not be hard to derive a class from `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` and add such interfaces to that class, but I'm unaware of any such standard interface.  `ILookup` is vaguely similar, but quite different.